# What happen if I install ubuntu without unlocking 'secure boot' & 'fast boot' on windows pre-installed computer? -pastebin attached

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

The desktop was using windows8. Not sure about the exact subversion but windows 8.

then I tried multi booting for the first time

So I downloaded ubuntu14.04 into usb.

Run the UUI for booting in USB.

Tried install as it goes

But didn't know the windows were on secureboot & fast boot

ubuntu just finished installing straight up without asking partition

Somehow I suceeded in booting ubuntu but I cannot boot with windows

I tried boot-repair but I still doesn't have access to it

Here is the pastebin [http://paste.ubuntu.com/17840206/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5tUZ.png)

I urgently need helps.. hope I have any exit

Is there any way to get the windows8 back?

---

But.. What should I do if there are no windows like partition?

[cannot upload images due to low level.. this is a link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5tUZ.png)

Comment: Can you please don't repost the same question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[multibooting\]Soooo urgently need helps in recovering boot windows8(ubuntu 14.04) - paste bin attached](http://askubuntu.com/questions/791184/multibootingsoooo-urgently-need-helps-in-recovering-boot-windows8ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: edwinksl 
sorry for bothering. I will remove my previouse question.
But  still i urgently need to fix this issue...
Is there any article I would  follow?

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if Windows is still there (not erased by mistake). Boot into a Live Ubuntu and open GParted. Check partition map and look for ntfs partitions labeled msftdata, Windows, etc.
2. If Windows is still there, insert the Win install disk and reboot into it (remove the Live Ubuntu medium while restarting the PC). Let the Wins install process begin and choose 'Repair Windows' option when asked for it.

At this point, you got Windows 'back', but you can't boot into Ubuntu anymore. The following steps are beyond the point of your original question, but i somehow feel you might find them useful in case you may want to dual-boot Win+Ubuntu.

3. Let the repair process finish, then reboot into the installed Windows. Go to Settings and disable "Fast Boot'.
4. Reboot into the BIOS/UEFI menu, go to Security Options and disable Secure Boot. Some firmware may not have such option. Not to worry. Just leave it as it is and reboot.
5. Boot into a Live Ubuntu and install `boot-repair` like this: Open a Terminal window and type:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
   Let the repair process finish and reboot (remove the live Ubuntu medium in the process). The GRUB menu should appear presenting options to boot in Win or Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your kind comment !! You are angel

Comment: Thanks  you so much for thoughful comment, but
what should I do if I cannot find windows on step 1 ?

Comment: @acuacal: If you can't find any ntfs partition larger than 10 - 15GB, it means Windows got erased somehow while installing Ubuntu. Obviously, you'll have to reinstall Win. The bad part is that the Win product key (that extremely long number) is forever lost. You can't retrieve it from the PC. Maybe you're lucky and find it in the original package of the PC.